# Cannot establish IP communication with IBM Server Connectivity Module

Tags: networking, ip, ibm, bladecenter

I have attached an IBM Server Connectivity Module in Bay2 of our BladeCenter E and tried to setup some networking between an external unmanaged switch and the internal blade servers.

I plugged a cable between port 1 of IBM SCM and another port in the unmanaged switch. This switch have a 10.0.0.0/24 network. But nothing happened. I've fixed the IP address 10.0.0.2 in the second interface of a blade server and I was unable to ping anything. The LED's on the IBM SCM stays off.

I don't know what's wrong and why it isn't working. If I disable the IBM SCM, at least we get link down in the OS, but there's no IP communication at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the web interface (aka MM, AMM) named something like 'allow external communication' if I remember correctly. Otherwise the switch only allows the blades to communicate between themselves.